# Exported jar file doesn't regconize SqlMapConfig.xml

Tags: java

I'd like to export my Java project using Eclipse Export capability. My project includes many Spring libs. I did right click project/Export/JAR file, chose project, checked everything of the project, specified Main Class. When I run it with arguments, errors occur. How to fix it?

```
F:\Downloads\MyProject>java -jar release.jar --d 2014/03/17 --l 1 --s 9001
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/b
eans/factory/BeanFactory
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.B
eanFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
```

**Update:**
I tried to export it as Runnable JAR file. It shows the below error. (Sorry I cannot post whole error log because of security)

```
....
    Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.
    FileNotFoundException: ibatis\SqlMapConfig.xml (The system cannot find the path
    specified)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
    ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
    y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
    an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
    (AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
    preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finish
    BeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
    h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
            at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<
    init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
            at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<
    init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
            at net.webike.japan.spring.batch.GlobalEstimateProcessExec.process(Globa
    lEstimateProcessExec.java:148)
            at net.webike.japan.spring.batch.GlobalEstimateProcessExec.main(GlobalEs
    timateProcessExec.java:120)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ibatis\SqlMapConfig.xml (The system ca
    nnot find the path specified)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.getInputStream(FileSys
    temResource.java:113)
            at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean.buildSqlMapCli
    ent(SqlMapClientFactoryBean.java:336)
            at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean.afterPropertie
    sSet(SqlMapClientFactoryBean.java:291)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
            ... 13 more
```

**Update:**
spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Database -->
    <bean id="test" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        </property>

        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:mysql://myip/myProject?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=SJIS</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>test</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>test</value>
        </property>
        <property name="maxActive" value="30" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="8" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="-1" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select version()" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="test" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>ibatis/SqlMapConfig.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref local="dsGlobalRanking" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="SomethingDAO"
        class="mypackage.SomethingDAOImpl"
        scope="singleton">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="test" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Then I load it

```
String contextPath = "classpath:spring.xml";

BeanFactory context = 
    (BeanFactory) new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(contextPath);
```

Comment: May be you need to export as Runnable Jar file instead of Jar file!!

Comment: You need to set the class path to tell the JVM where the spring library jars are found.

Comment: @Henry: But the Spring libs were included in project with relative path (using "Right Click / Add to Build Path").

Comment: @Emerald214 thats just for Eclipse to find it during compilation (and execution within Eclipse). To make them available at run time use the class path (command line parameter or environment variable).

Comment: So is there any way to package all in one? Asumming I run that jar file on another machine.

Comment: Could you post your spring.xml file? Just the tag with "class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean"" attribute

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have *SqlMapConfig.xml* inside the Jar, for example in the position:

> /res/ibatis/SqlMapConfig.xml

You should reference it in the **spring.xml** file as the following:

```
<bean id="sqlMapClient" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/res/ibatis/SqlMapConfig.xml"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="yourDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

(note the *classpath:* marker)

Comment: I tried by it doesn't work >> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ibatis/SqlMapConfig.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: check if, after opening the jar with for example winzip, it does contain /res/ibatis/SqlMapConfig.xml

Comment: Jar file does not contain SqlMapConfig in jar. How to fix it?

Comment: manually, you can add that file to the jar by using winzip (on the correct path). Or you can edit your Maven or ANT build configuration.